# Understanding proof of uniqueness in theorem on polynomial interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

There is a slight part of the following proof in my textbook which I don't quite get.

THEOREM

If $x_0, x_1,...,x_n$ are distinct real numbers, then for arbitrary values $y_0, y_1,...,y_n$, there is a unique polynomial $p_n$ of degree at most $n$ such that

$$p_n(x_i) = y_i \quad (0 \leq i \leq n)$$

PROOF

Let us prove the uniqueness or *unicity* first.  Suppose there were two such polynomials, $p_n$ and $q_n$.  Then the polynomial $p_n - q_n$ would have the property $(p_n - q_n)(x_i) = 0$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$.  Since the degree of $p_n - q_n$ can be at most $n$, this polynomial can have at most $n$ zeros if it is not the $0$ polynomial.  Since the $x_i$ are distinct, $p_n - q_n$ has $n+1$ zeros; it must therefore be $0$.  Hence, $p_n = q_n$.

OK, so the only thing I don't quite here is the part:

"Since the $x_i$ are distinct, $p_n - q_n$ has $n+1$ zeros"

How does it follow that this must have exactly $n+1$ zeros.  I have pondered this for some time, but just can't see why this is obvious.  I'm probably overlooking something simple here, but if anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you agree with the statement that $(p_n - q_n)(x_i)$ would be equal to $0$ for $i = 0,1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: Yes!  See below.  I understand it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't know that it has exactly $n+1$ zeros, just that it has at least that many because you have found them:  $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$.  But an $n^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial can only have $n$ zeros, unless it is identically zero...

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I get it now :).  Really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "Since the $x_i$ are distinct, $p_n - q_n$ has $n+1$ zeros" is intended to mean that there are **at least** $n+1$ zeros. It would have been a little better to say "at least," but being absolutely precise can be a bit tedious.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Yes, I get it now :)